# the script for deleting files and folders consumes a lot of memory resources

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a script to delete files and folders, but it eats up all the RAM, eats up a lot of memory resources
, a folder that is parsed 1tb and new files are being written to it in parallel. What can I do to make the script eat not so many resources?
there are 48 GB of RAM on the server ( when the script does not work, 28 GB is used in ) that is, 20 RAM goes to the script

```
import os, time, shutil

path = "/data/decision/"
now = time.time()

with open ('/root/decisionlist', 'w+') as f:
        for filename in os.listdir(path):
                if os.stat(os.path.join(path, filename)).st_mtime < now - 30*86400:
                        f.write(os.path.join(path, filename)+'\n')
with open('/root/decisionlist', 'r') as filetodelete:
        for line in filetodelete:
                shutil.rmtree(line)

os.remove('/root/decisionlist')
```

Comment: Why are you writing the results into a file instead of simply adding to a list in memory? Having said that, nothing here should be consuming a lot of RAM, though running `stat` on every file is moderately expensive in terms of running time (but unavoidable for this specific task).

Comment: If you have several of these running at the same time, avoiding the parallel writes to the same output file should straighten things out in more ways than one (but not running more than one is probably a better solution still).

Comment: @tripleee I tried it directly, too, the memory is draining. I think the problem is in the folder itself, its weight is very large, and there are a lot of small directories inside,resources are spent on parsing, as I understand it

Comment: I don't think you indicated your OS, your disk type (spinning, SSD, NVMe), your filesystem, or how many files you have on the filesystem... Did you try with `find ... -delete` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell oracle linux(ssd)

Comment: @MarkSetchell objects 75969036 . Yes, we just started with find ...

Comment: `os.listdir` builds and returns a list of all file and folder names. If there are really very much items, this could explain the memory usage. You could try `os.scandir`, `glob.iglob` or the `pathlib` instead.